# Why am I getting a "port 22: Connection refused" error?

Tags: 12.04, ssh

I am getting a

```
port 22: Connection refused
```

error while connecting to a server.

I have both the openssh client and server installed, and they are running. But still there is an error. Please help.

Comment: Just to clarify, is openssh server installed on the server?

Comment: Check ssh is running on port 22 and if you have a firewall rule blocking the port.

Comment: According to me , Configure firewall such that it allows to ssh (port 22 ) which is currently blocked by firewall.

Comment: sudo ufw enable http://askubuntu.com/questions/417998/why-ubuntu-firewall-not-showing-verbose

Comment: This could occur probably because of temporary network loss too. So check your internet connection.

Comment: This might be useful if you were to explain how to do what you suggest. As is, not so much. Related: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/troubleshooting-telnet

Comment: I can't seem to answer for some reason. But I had the same issue working with MAC M1, for me the solution was changing the system setting through system preferences as described here:
https://superuser.com/a/190610/917327

Answer (score 118):

I went through this issue and finally got appropriate answer.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Then went into `raspi-config` in a terminal window and enabled ssh.

This will allow port 22 to be used for sshd.

Comment: Same problem here as @SDsolar

Comment: @Nadiv, I also had to use raspi-config to enable ssh.  Answer has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Performed the first three lines on both computers and the file is now successfully transferred. Why does Ubuntu not come with these installed/enabled by default? The `connection refused` error is so cryptic, I had no idea if it was a firewall issues, username issue, IP address issue, etc etc. Very frustrating.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 22` worked once. Again the error started appearing.

Answer (score 36):

While on the server, check to make sure sshd is actually running, and is listening on port 22:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1538/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1538/sshd
```

If you don't get results, or they don't show you're listening on tcp 0.0.0.0:22... fix that.

If you DO show that sshd is running and is listening on tcp port 22, check to make sure there's no firewall rule getting in the way.  Again, on the server:

```
$ sudo iptables -L | grep ssh
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
```

Or alternately,

```
$ sudo ufw verbose
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         DENY        Anywhere
22/tcp                     DENY        Anywhere
```

If you do see a rule like one of the ones above, you'll need to fix that.

If you don't see any firewall rules in the way and you do see the service running on the server, then it's time to check your workstation, and the network it's connected to.  Can you connect to other servers? Can you ping your own interface or loopback address? Etc.

Comment: and if you can connect to other servers?

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, mine is not port 22, its 2222. You said, fix that, but how?

Comment: Mine gave no results.

Comment: fix it with: `sudo ufw allow 22` (or whatever your port is)

Comment: No firewall rules in the server. But still SSH is allowed from the PCs in the local network and not from outside our lab (but in the same institute network)

Comment: I still can't connect. Is iptables interferring with ufw?

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

it worked for me :)

Probably not the most *orthodox* solution... :)

Comment: Using dpkg-reconfigure would possible be easier to use in lieu of an uninstall/reinstall solution

Comment: I had to use apt-get purge openssh-server (instead of remove) to get it to work.

Answer (score 8):

Came across same problem after installing Raspbian. Solution that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: If this worked you must have changed your sshd-config before.

Comment: I edited sshd_config on Raspbian while trying to setup ssh. This solution worked for me.

Comment: +1. Only solution that worked!

Answer (score 5):

The following commands worked for me:

```
cd /root/.ssh
vi known_hosts
```

Now delete everything in that file and enter on the terminal:

```
service sshd restart
```

Source: [SSH - Connection Refused](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ssh-connection-refused-339510/)

Comment: similar problem for me, but I cleared my known_hosts with `ssh-keygen -f "/home/MYUSER/.ssh/known_hosts" -R MYHOST`, substituting in my linux user and remote host I was trying to connect to

Comment: What are `known_hosts` and why does knowing some hosts prevent the machine from connecting?

Answer (score 2):

The static IP was wrong in my case. Found out by doing `ping <my_ip>` after switching off the server. It was still pinging even when the server was off. Correcting the IP solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might fix it for you as well. Try port forwarding connection 22 from your outgoing IP address to your local IP on the same port. Worked for me allowing me to ssh in to remote ubuntu computer.