# ssh: connect to host <usrname>@....org port 22: Connection refused

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am trying to use ssh to connect to a server and it worked fine just yesterday. However today it failed and when I tried to test with `ssh localhost`, it worked. Below is the output of the failure:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to boa-cheng.duckdns.org [155.33.213.0] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 155.33.213.0 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host boa-cheng.duckdns.org port 22: Connection refused
```

Can anybody give some advice and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a "port 22: Connection refused" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218344/why-am-i-getting-a-port-22-connection-refused-error)