# How To Transfer Files Between Two Ubuntu Machines Connected Via RJ45?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, samba

I have a desktop PC running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS & Laptop running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS. I would like to transfer files from Desktop to my laptop using Samba (or whatever else). Can anyone guide me (or link me tuts) for it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to network two Ubuntu computers using ethernet (without a router)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22835/how-to-network-two-ubuntu-computers-using-ethernet-without-a-router)

Comment: It doesn't really matter what your machines are connected over, and the general question is [Best way to transfer files over a LAN between two Linux computers](https://superuser.com/questions/326211/best-way-to-transfer-files-over-a-lan-between-two-linux-computers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TCP as well :
[How to network two Ubuntu computers using ethernet (without a router)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22835/how-to-network-two-ubuntu-computers-using-ethernet-without-a-router)

Looks this question has been asked before, just install openssh-ssh server it's easier to use rsync with this tool

Answer (score -2):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=install+smb+ubuntu

3rd one down looks good. Just install on both computers.

You could also use rsync to keep the same folders on both machines, or SCP/SFTP if you want to get crazy with it.