# Headless RPI (ssh) over ethernet cable

Tags: ssh, ethernet, raspberrypi

I want to control a robot using RPI (headless) over ssh. In my current setup this goes over the network but I want it to go over an ethernet cable. I have a motherboard (FTW-K x99) with double network connectors and controllers (Intel I218 and Qualcomm E2400).

How would I go about connecting via ssh to the RPI with a direct ethernet cable without display?

I've seen https://askubuntu.com/a/26770/621294 but I don't how it goes with RPI.

ifconfig Desktop

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.192.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.192.255
    inet6 fe80::599f:859a:...  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2a02:1812:2e08:...  prefixlen 64  
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::6831:a338:...  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:1f:bc:11:..:..  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1482  bytes 180147 (175.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 45904  bytes 3062874 (2.9 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xfb500000-fb520000
```

ifconfig Rpi (Note that it's connected to the internet now, I don't have a monitor for the Pi)

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c3:5f:7b  
      inet addr:192.168.192.247  Bcast:192.168.192.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5d00:1308:170b:da7d/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a02:1812:2e08:7300:3e7c:8ccf:e9ba:858b/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:24305 (23.7 KiB)  TX bytes:36150 (35.3 KiB)
```

Comment: You will need to assign both the RPi's NIC and the NIC on your motherboard static IP addresses in the same subnet. Then, simply connect the Ethernet cable to both NICs and SSH away! (Note that a crossover cable is not required as modern NICs are smart enough to automatically crossover)

Comment: @AndroidDev Thank you, I set the IP's to 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 and the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0. This gives me a "No route to host" error in ssh.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output of `ifconfig` for both the Pi and your computer?