# how to transfer files ubuntu 20.04 pc with windows pc through ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet

i am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS and i have a windows laptop. i have tried many ways to connect those with an etharnet cable. i have shown every youtube tutorial to do so but there is no settings of wired connection in the settings menu. please help me to connect those pc via etharnet cable for file shareing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to network two Ubuntu computers using ethernet (without a router)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22835/how-to-network-two-ubuntu-computers-using-ethernet-without-a-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a samba server on your ubuntu computer, then upload your files from your pc to your ubuntu computer.

You can also use SFTP, which uses the SSH protocol. All you have to do is enable SSH on your computer.

Comment: can you show me the process how to do that

Comment: Type `sudo apt install openssh-server` to enable ssh on your ubuntu computer, then type `hostname -I` tp get your localip. On your other pc, install FileZilla, and use it to connect using SFTP, not FTP. Your username is the same as on your Ubuntu computer. If you're not sure on how to use FileZila, there are a ton of tutorials online.