# How do I share my laptop's wireless connection with my Android phone?

Tags: wireless, android, wireless-access-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share a wired Internet connection with an Android phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67663/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-with-an-android-phone)

I want to use the internet connection of my wired UBUNTU 10.04 machine in my Samsung Note android phone through wireless. I have USB wireless adapter with chip set RTL8187B. I don't want to change my original android into Cynogenmod or something else. I don't want to be superuser in Android. I don't want to disturb my android till warranty period of my mobile phone.

How it is possible? Any idea? Please give your comments :)

I tried infrastructure/adhoc wireless connections with WPA key security. But, android is not detecting wireless signal from my UBUNTU computer. The USB wireless devise is connected well in computer with driver support.