# Sharing ethernet with Android device

Tags: wireless, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)

I used connectify on Windows, I'm looking for something similar to share my ethernet on laptop connection with my Nexus S.

I tried adhoc mode already(as described in [How to share a wired Internet connection with an Android phone (reverse-tethering)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67663/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-with-an-android-phone)), but that won't work since I'm running stock Android 4.2 and not CM.

Comment: I can make the Android device as a wifi hotspot, if it helps.