# how to use my wired connection internet for accessing internet on mobile phones

Tags: 14.04, lts

how to use my wired connection internet for accessing internet on mobile phones.i am unable to create hotspot.
command "sudo-ap hotspot" start says not found

Comment: Using wired internet on a phone doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu. Reword your question to be asking about your problem with creating a hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a solution for this, and have tried a number of things, without success.
This post may help you [How to share a wired Internet connection with an Android phone (reverse-tethering)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67663/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-with-an-android-phone-reverse-tetherin)

Comment: Hi Raouf, While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.