# how to share WIFI internet to LAN port?

Tags: wireless, configuration, internet, lan

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10

I have internet in mobile then create hotspot for access internet in laptop.

Now main thing is that how can I share that to LAN(eth0).

### Path of internet

**Mobile WIFI --> Laptop WIFI --> Laptop Lan --> Smart TV Lan**

Comment: Check this Question: [Share Wireless connection with Wired Ethernet Port](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port?rq=1)

Comment: flagged as a possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/q/171914/65926)

Comment: I have asked this question before you linked question @EricCarvalho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a NAT/Firewall software like Firestarter on the LAPTOP (install from the software center).

Another solution without running anything is to do the NAT manually with iptables on NAT Table postrouting using Masquerade on your wi-fi interface. See rule below:

`-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`

and you will need to enable ip forwarding with:

`/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

or make it permanent with:

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Modify the line:
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Apply:
`sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

Verify:
`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Should show 1