# How to show the reserved leases that dhcp has on file?

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip, dhcpd, dynamic-ip

I want to check on the reserved leases (called "fixed-address" in the config files) of my dhcpd. To get all the info about the free dynamic ips is no problem, but the reserved one that get written to a MAC address are not shown in any file that I could imagine to be connected to dhcpd.

Best would be if I could see if the reservation is active and if not, since when it has not been used. That way I could declare that device as gone and mark the reservation as free for new ones.

For the normal leases I use this answer with the python script: [How do I show active dhcp leases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219609/how-do-i-show-active-dhcp-leases)

That works pretty good as long as it is not a reserved one.

Maybe someone out there has an answer to that.

Comment: Just had a comment that wanted me to check the dhcp.lease file ... that got deleted straight away by the writer.

dhcp.lease does not contain the reservations!

That only lists the dynamic leases. Which is the problem and the reason for me asking this.

Comment: I have (from a previous installation) a number of files called `dhclient-08fbe445-3a4e-4352-a138-ac38b7d654b7-eth1.lease` and the like in the same directory. Don't these contain reservations?

Comment: No that seem to be files of the dhclient so the files of the dynamic device where it stores its own info that it got from a dhcp server. I am looking for the reservations of dhcpd on my ubuntu server and the info on the active objects of the dhcp server and the active reservations in my complete networks.