# How do I share my wireless connection via a wired cable?

Tags: wireless, ethernet, connection-sharing

Im trying to share the wireless from my netbook eeepc to my desktop computer that does not have any wifi, it can run internet through a cable connected to my internet router but im wondering if there is any way to share my netbooks wireless through the ethernet cable. the desktop is running on 12.04 and the eeepc is running on 12.10

Comment: Refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port) askubuntu Question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/q/171914/65926)

Answer (score 7):

This is surprisingly easy at least with Ubuntu 12.04.  I have not personally been able to test this on 12.10 but It has been confirmed that this works there too.  I use the Gnome Classic desktop but similar steps should work with any desktop.

I'm connecting my Windows 7 machine to the internet via the Wifi on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

step 1
[image: step1]

step 2
[image: step2]

step 3
[image: step3]

Comment: It works the same with 12.10

Comment: @Jean-Marie thanks for the confirmation.  I've edited my answer to include this.