# Wifi disconnects when Ethernet connected

Tags: 12.10, wireless, internet, windows-xp, ethernet

I'm using a WiFi connection on Ubuntu 12 and connecting to XP directly via Ethernet cable. I've set the ipv4 settings of the Ubuntu wired connection to:

> share with other computers

and restarted. If the network cable is plugged in WiFi disables. Is this problem on the XP side? IP is set to automatically obtain etc. I'm only looking to share the internet access. Thanks.

Comment: I did this successfully [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266112/how-do-i-share-my-wireless-connection-via-a-wired-cable/266197#266197) with Windows 7 wired to my Ubuntu 12.04 machine using The Wifi on the Ubuntu PC to connect both computers via my router to the internet.  Works for me -- What's different about you set up?  Ubuntu version for example?

Comment: Hey Im using 12.10 and xp with service pack 3. I can't find anything to fix this problem... Im assuming it's something to do with the xp side any help would be great.

Comment: Are you using a cross-over cable or a standard straight-through Ethernet cable?

Comment: I believe an Ethernet cable its worked before with sharing xp to xp.

Answer (score 0):

Umm...by default, ubuntu disconnects wireless networks if an active ethernet cable is connected. i dont think there is a way of bypassing that