# Generating Wi-fi for mobile phone from linux

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, hot-spot

I use ubuntu 12.04 and wish to share its internet with my wi-fi enabled phone.

I know how to use wireless network as hotspot using GUI. But it works only for other laptops. My android phone can't even detect it. Is there a way to generate wi-fi so that I can share my laptop Internet with my phone?

I have tried the following link, but due to some reason, it stops my laptop Internet as well.

http://thebeautifullmind.com/2012/09/19/sharing-internet-over-wifi-between-ubuntu-and-android/

Also, can anybody please explain how is the wi-fi generated? I know how to create a DHCP server by editing the configuration file. So, I used to think that when I click "Use as Hotspot", some configuration file changes as a result of which Internet is shared with other devices. If so, why wouldn't a mobile detect the hotspot and a laptop has no difficulty in using the shared Internet?

Please help.

Comment: Andriod doesn't supoprt ad hoc mode. You can look here to setup in AP mode- [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)

Comment: If you are connecting your laptop to the internet via a wired connection [This may be the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/266197/107450)

Comment: No I want to connect my android phone