# DHCP working but clients don't have internet

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Just as the title says. My DHCP assigns IP addresse and all that stuff to clients; however clients don't have access to the Internet. Here's my DHCP configuration:

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name "home.lan";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option broadcast-address 10.8.8.255;
subnet 10.8.8.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 10.8.8.5 10.8.8.9;
 option routers 10.8.8.1;
}
broadcast-address 10.8.8.255
```

I have of course added `INTERFACES="eth0"` in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`
and added eth0 interface definition to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.8.8.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.8.8.1
broadcast 10.8.8.255
```

I've added `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

On the net, I've read that it is possible to simply share the net using linux GUI.
([here's easy guide with screenshots on how to share the connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/266197/107450))
But it doesn't work in my case. If I change on my wlan0 (auto DHCP) to (share to other computers) I don't have internet access after rebooting because wlan0 do not automatically get connection info.

Clients receive IP, default gateway, DNS'es, netmask and so.
Mind any of u helping me with finding out, why it is not working?
Im using ubuntu 12.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first steps look fine, but you also have to setup IP masquarding(NAT) using `iptables`.

Issue the following commands:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ethX -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

That assumes that `eth0` is your local LAN and `ethX` is your external interface(inet).
I also suggest you put these commands into a init script, since they are volatile, the iptables rules are lost after a reboot.

Before you continue i suggest you Google for "Ubuntu NAT", there are a lot of solutions for that problem with ready to use scripts.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/network/interfaces the address of the (remote) gateway should not be the same as the address of the local interface.