# Forward laptop's WiFi into PC Ethernet

Tags: internet, ethernet, tethering

I need to do a few things that can only be done on my computer, but my home internet is broken this week. The only way to get internet is on my phone. I turn on tethering and my phone acts like a WiFi router which allows my laptop to access the internet, but I need my Desktop to have internet because of the programs requirements to turn on. To reword, my phone has 3G and acts like a WiFi hotspot which my laptop receives because it has a WiFi card, but it also has an Ethernet port. I need to use my cable and connect the Ethernet port so that my laptop acts like a router and my PC can have access to internet but I don't know how to configure the laptop to do that. Both my computer and laptop have 14.04. What program allows me to do this Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/q/171914/65926)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this should be easily doable.

> It's ridiculously easy. Simply right click on your network manager and
>   choose "Edit Connections". Then in the "Wired" tab, you can either use
>   your existing wired connection, (or create a new one by hitting the
>   "Add" button, name your new connection "Shared Network Port" or
>   something similar), pop into its IPv4 tab and in "Method", choose
>   "Shared to other computers". Apply everything and close the network
>   manager windows.
>
> Now when you need to plug something into that ethernet port, you can
>   share your WIFI internet conenction simply by clicking on network
>   manager and choosing the "Shared Network Port" entry there.
>
> If you want this to be a constantly used ethernet connection used for
>   sharing and nothing else, feel free to edit "Auto Eth0" instead of
>   creating a new entry like I describe above. Creating a new entry gives
>   you some flexibility to choose however.
>
> Note that this uses a bit of NAT (network address translation) magic
>   to work properly, so the Xbox360 (or whatever you plug into your wired
>   port) will get a funky IP address.
>
> From memory, it will only be able to see the internet too - I don't
>   think you can see the host computer, the one with the internet
>   connection. You can set that up, but it requires a bit of messing
>   about with DHCP servers, I believe. I didn't need it, so I didn't go
>   down that road.
>   Source: [Share Wireless connection with Wired Ethernet Port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port)