# Piggy back ubuntu desktop on my windows laptop wifi so the desktop can access the internet?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet

I need to have internet on my ubuntu / mint desktop. The only way I can get online right now is wifi and I couldn't get the USB Netgear WNA3100 to work because without internet packages won't install for me to get the driver.

I need my ubuntu / mint desktop to access the internet through an ethernet cable to my laptop running windows 8.1 so it can get online. I'm not able to hook up to a router modem at all since its on the other side of the house.

[ ubuntu [ ethernet ] -- -- -- -- [ win 8.1 [ wifi ] = [ ubuntu [ ethernet access from windows wifi ]

How can I make this work because it desperately desperately absolutely needs to be and has to get online. I can not afford to wait one week.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible options and alternatives I can suggest:

- Download the driver on Windows machine, save on USB, transfer to Ubuntu, install that driver with `sudo dpkg -i package-file`.
- Boot that Windows machine with an Ubuntu Live CD or USB that you used for installing Ubuntu (hopefully you still have it) and use that live desktop in as wifi to ethernet source as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/518954/295286)
- Use usb tethering from a smartphone. If you don't have one, ask a friend, and find out who will help you in the time of need.
- If everything fails with that Netgear dongle, buy usb dongle with [RTL8192 chipset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AVSRLTO) cheap and works out of the box. I've used it on two laptops with Ubuntu, one PC, and one Windows PC. No driver installation necessary (on the Linux side, but on Windows you will have to install it from a cd that comes with the package) and signal is strong even in the most bricked-up buildings on my college campus.

Comment: He, there's no correction for me. ;)

Comment: @A.B. there must be at least some grammar mistakes somewher ;)