# +Sharing wireless via ethernet. Problem

Tags: networking, wireless, lan, sharing

I have a computer running Ubuntu 12.04 connected to our house wireless network and I would like to share this connection with a Lubuntu machine I'm setting up via direct ethernet. I have connected the two via ethernet, setting my wireless connected machine's wired connection to 'share with other machines'. I can ping from one machine to the other (when I turn off the firewall), but I can't access the internet on my Lubuntu machine, with a browser, or by pinging 8.8.8.8, www.google.etc.It just times-out.

As stated above, I repeat it here for emphasis, I have connected the two machines via ethernet by setting the IPv4 to 'Share to other computers' and by manually configuring the address on my second computer.

UPDATE: I have to add another test I just completed. I booted from a live USB and was able to connect my second computer to shared internet very easily. Following the same procedures on my installation it is still not working

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port

Comment: I have to add another test I just completed. I booted from a live USB and was able to connect my second computer to shared internet very easily. Following the same procedures on my installation still not working.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I have tried adding ip addresses to /etc/resolv.conf, flushing iptables, and many other options and still nothing works.

Comment: After upgrading to 14.04 I can now share my internet using the conventional instructions. I suspect this was an issue with some firewall config that people have not pinpointed. Unfortunately I can't retrospectively search it out so this question needs to be closed without a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear this was never answered or fully addressed. I solved the problem by upgrading but never in the original installation.